# Lenovo Carbon X1 2018 Virtual Box

Tags: virtualbox, cpu, 18.04

I encountered multiple problems setting up Virtualbox on ubuntu 17.10 and ubuntu 18.04 on the new Lenovo Carbon X1 2018. First there was a Problem with the cpu throtteling, i tried solving this with the fix from archlinux https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Lenovo_ThinkPad_X1_Carbon_(Gen_6)#Temporary_fix

now i encounter another problem with this fix:

```
[ 1230.951665] systemd[1]: systemd 237 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN2 +IDN -PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid)
[ 1230.969574] systemd[1]: Detected architecture x86-64.
[ 1230.987604] systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/cpu-throttling.timer:8: Unknown lvalue 'Requires' in section 'Timer'
[ 1230.987637] systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/cpu-throttling.service:8: Unknown section 'Timer'. Ignoring.
[ 1231.120222] systemd[1]: systemd 237 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN2 +IDN -PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid)
[ 1231.120435] systemd[1]: Detected architecture x86-64.
[ 1231.135275] systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/cpu-throttling.timer:8: Unknown lvalue 'Requires' in section 'Timer'
[ 1231.135307] systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/cpu-throttling.service:8: Unknown section 'Timer'. Ignoring.
[ 1231.169433] systemd[1]: Started ACPI event daemon.
[ 1231.169454] systemd[1]: Started CUPS Scheduler.
[ 1231.273816] systemd[1]: systemd 237 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN2 +IDN -PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid)
[ 1231.274193] systemd[1]: Detected architecture x86-64.
[ 1231.293443] systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/cpu-throttling.timer:8: Unknown lvalue 'Requires' in section 'Timer'
[ 1231.293485] systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/cpu-throttling.service:8: Unknown section 'Timer'. Ignoring.
[ 1231.330142] systemd[1]: Started CUPS Scheduler.
[ 1231.402913] systemd[1]: systemd 237 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN2 +IDN -PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid)
[ 1231.403085] systemd[1]: Detected architecture x86-64.
[ 1231.419010] systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/cpu-throttling.timer:8: Unknown lvalue 'Requires' in section 'Timer'
[ 1231.419041] systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/cpu-throttling.service:8: Unknown section 'Timer'. Ignoring.
[ 1231.449354] systemd[1]: Started ACPI event daemon.
[ 1231.449476] systemd[1]: Started CUPS Scheduler.
```

Has anyone a fix for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Arch Wiki is incorrect. You need to remove the "Requires" line in the *.timer file and remove the "[Timer]" section in the *.service.

---

I have updated the Arch Wiki to reflect this.